# Trouble Figuring Out Join Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Accounts, Tickets, Groups:

```
# group.rb
has_many :tickets
has_many :accounts, :through => :assignments
has_many :assignments

# ticket.rb
belongs_to :group, :class_name => "Group", :foreign_key => "group_id"
has_many :accounts , :through => :assignments
has_many :assignments

# account.rb
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :group_ids, :role
has_many :tickets, :through => :assignments
has_many :assignments    
has_many :groups, :through => :assignments
has_many :assignments

#assignment.rb
belongs_to :account
belongs_to :ticket
belongs_to :group
```

I want to list the tickets where it's group belongs to the `current_account`'s `group_id`s.

For some reason it's been boggling my brain all day and it seems like it should be super simple but I can't figure it out.

## UPDATE

I also have named scopes for the Ticket model as well:

```
  scope :not_archived, where('archived != ?', 1)
  scope :is_archived, where('archived = ?', 1)
```

So I'd need to able to append `.not_archived` or `.is_archived` as well to the. So not sure if @Veraticus answer would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a named scope on a ticket that takes a account as an argument:

```
#ticket.rb
scope :for_account lambda { |account| joins(:group => :accounts ).where("accounts.id = ?", account.id) }
```

which should generate sql like:

```
SELECT ticets.* FROM ticket
INNER JOIN groups ON tickets.groups_id = groups.id
  INNER JOIN accounts ON groups.account_id = accounts.id
WHERE accounts.id = x
```

You can then call:

```
Ticket.for_account(current_account)
```

To get tickets for current account and it'll pull it all out in one query. You can then chain this with any other scopes you want as well e.g.

```
Ticket.not_archived.for_account(current_account)
```

Comment: Ok now I'm getting this `Association named 'account' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: and there should be a comma after `scope :for_account`

Comment: ok now with the `accounts` in the `join` i now get this: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: account.id: SELECT  "tickets".* FROM "tickets" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "tickets"."group_id" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "groups"."id" = "assignments"."group_id" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "assignments"."account_id" WHERE (archived != 1) AND (account.id = 1) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0`

Comment: I think in the previous edit I corrected account.id to accounts.id. Check yours is using .where("accounts.id = ? ", account.id)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
current_account.groups.collect(&:tickets)
```

That will return an array of all the arrays of the tickets attached to the current_account's groups. If you want it as just one big array, you can call flatten at the end:

```
current_account.groups.collect(&:tickets).flatten
```

If you have a scope to apply, I'd do something like this:

```
current_account.groups.collect{|g| g.tickets.not_archived.all}.flatten
```

With you replacing the scope with whatever you want.

Comment: What if I want to loop through them like on a standard index page?

Comment: Never mind... I did a loop on current_account.groups.collect(&:tickets).flatten and that worked. Is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: It's pretty efficient... if you're looking for more efficiency you can do current_account.groups.include(:tickets)... but if you're applying a scope then a lot of the included results will be pruned out anyway. Also see my edit.